# Pagination using bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'mt trying to use the Boststrap pagination for my php file (vistapart.php) but looks like this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img59/3215/0cmx.jpg

Instead of like this example: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination

This is my code where I do and display the pagination:

```
$display=10;

if(isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])){
    $pages=$_GET['p'];
}else{
    $q="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM participante";
    $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    $row = @mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM);
    $records=$row[0];
    //a partir de aqui calcula numero de paginas
    if($records>$display){
        $pages=ceil($records/$display);
    }else{
        $pages=1;
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['s']) && is_numeric($_GET['s'])){
    $start=$_GET['s'];      
}else{
    $start=0;
}

....

if($pages>1){
    echo '<br /><p><ul class="pagination">';
    $current_page=($start/$display)+1;
    if($current_page!=1){
        echo '<li><a href="vistapart.php?s='.($start-$display).'&p='.$pages.'&sort='.$sort.'">&laquo;</a></li>';
    }
    for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++){
        if($i!=$current_page){
            echo '<li><a href="vistapart.php?s='.(($display*($i-1))).'&p='.$pages.'&sort='.$sort.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        }else{
            echo $i.'<li></li>';
        }
    }
    if($current_page!=$pages){
        echo '<li><a href="vistapart.php?s='.($start+$display).'&p='.$pages.'&sort='.$sort.'">&raquo;</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ul></p>';
}
```

What can be the problem? Thanks for the help.

Comment: can u post the html of whole <ul>  and try not to use it in a <p> tag

Comment: I would guess your problem has to do with how your HTML is getting rendered...it looks like you are missing a closing tag, or closing a tag soon based on your output...As @Tarun said, you will need to post the resulting HTML so that we can see what the problem is.

Comment: You want to see all the html code or what, @Tarun? (I can't understand your question)

Comment: This: imageshack.com/a/img856/6665/qv9a.jpg ?

Comment: i meant the source code of the html, just `CTRL+U`  copy paste the complete source or just the pagination part

Comment: The code: http://pastebin.com/fRHftGR4

The CSS code: http://pastebin.com/h39pRYus

Answer (score 0):

The error is on line `echo $i.'<li></li>';`. Change it to `echo "<li>{$i}</li>";` like this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++){
    if($i!=$current_page){
        echo '<li><a href="vistapart.php?s='.(($display*($i-1))).'&p='.$pages.'&sort='.$sort.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }else{
        echo "<li>{$i}</li>"; // <- change is here
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post HTML output then.

Comment: The code: pastebin.com/fRHftGR4 The CSS code: pastebin.com/h39pRYus